# Trying to call third party api through rest-client giving RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I am trying to call rest api of https://example.com but getting above error pls help me with the same

Answer (score 0):

To bypass verify SSL certificate you can use :verify_ssl => false like this

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://example.com/', :method => :get, :verify_ssl => false)
```

Just in case that doesn't work also put `:proxy => nil` like this

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://example.com/', :method => :get, :verify_ssl => false, :proxy => nil)
```

Comment: Thanks @meshin, I have already tried above but then it gives me "RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized" even if I pass user-id and password.